# ffmpeg **doubled** my duration

Tags: ffmpeg, quicktime

I'm using ffmpeg to convert a `PNG` image sequence into a `.mov` file with alpha channel for use in my NLE.

The `PNG` sequence was rendered out of DashWare where it was generated in sync with a 4m35s (approx) 1080p50 video clip.

As expected the image sequence consisted of just over 13,750 images.

I used the following command to convert these into the required `PNG` encoded, uncompressed `RGBA` (rgb32) `.mov` file.

```
ffmpeg -i imageSeq-%06d.png -vcodec png -r 50 -pix_fmt rgb32 -y video.mov
```

And the file converted OK *but* it's duration came out at 9m10s - exactly double what it should have been.

By my reckoning 4m35s at 50fps is: `((4x60)+35)x50` which is 13750 frames/images. So why did the duration double in conversion with the above command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, ffmpeg treats image sequence and raw video inputs as having a native rate of 25 fps unless told otherwise. So, the `-r 50` duplicates each frame.

Use

```
ffmpeg -framerate 50 -i imageSeq-%06d.png -vcodec png -pix_fmt rgb32 -y video.mov
```

You can skip the `-r 50` since ffmpeg will use the input's framerate.